# In $Z_{24}$, list all generators for the subgroup of order 8

Tags: abstract-algebra

Q. In $\Bbb Z_{24}$, list all generators for the subgroup of order $8$.

So, I know that the divisors of $24$ which are $1,2,3,4,6,8,12
$ and $24$ are the orders of the sets in the subgroup.

I'm not sure if this is a trick question but I was only able to find one generator which is $\langle 3\rangle$, so was the plural in generators unnecessary? Or am I missing a generator.

Comment: The group of order $8$ is cyclic, hence it has the same number of generators as $\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a cyclic group of $n$ elements has $\varphi(n)$ divisors, so you should have $\varphi(8)=4$ generators.

The subgroup of order $8$ is : $\{0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21\}$. The generators are: $\{3,9,15,21\}$

Comment: How did you get that set {3,9,15,21}?

Comment: you can look at your set as $\{0,3,2\cdot3,3\cdot3,4\cdot3,5\cdot3,6\cdot3,7\cdot 3\}$, you want the ones that have coefficients relatively prime the the order of the subgroup (Which is $8$)

Comment: got it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, $9,15$, and $21$ are also generators. In any cyclic group of order $n$ then generator of a subgroup of order $d$ has to form $g^m$ where the g.c.d $(m,n)=n/d$.

So, with $n=24$ and $d=3$, we want to find all numbers $m$ such that $1\le m\le 24$. $(m,24)=24/8=3$.

Running through the multiples of $3$ which are less than $24$ gives the generators $3,9,15,21$.

Comment: what is m in this case?

Comment: I'll add to my answer.